# Join two tables with where clause using CodeIginter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to load all the data from table "main_tests" where `main_tests.id = test_name_price.test_id` and where `test_name_price.list_id = 1`

I'm trying to do that but there it's just saying wrong syntax I'm beginner to CodeIginter Thanks For Advance

I have looked a lot for the answer but I couldn't get what I need exactly or either their ways don't work with me

here is my code

```
  $result =  $this->db->select('test_name_price.*, main_tests.*')
                                    ->from('test_name_price')
                                    ->where('test_name_price.list_id', 1)
                                    ->join('main_tests', 
                                  'test_name_price.test_id = main_tests.id')
                                    ->get();


                                if (count($result) > 0) {

                                    foreach ($result as $itemsl) {

                                        echo "


                    <option value='$itemsl->testname' data-code='$itemsl- 
                                      >test_code'>$itemsl->test_id</option>



                                         ";
                                    }
                                }

                                echo "</select>"
```

EDIT :

that's the code in my controller  , that view is addpatient

```
    public function addpatient()

{

      $this->load->model("khmodel","Khmodel");


     $this->load->view('addpatient', array('result_array' => 
           $result_array));


}
```

and here is my view

```
      <?php foreach ($result_array as $key => $value) : ?>


        <option value='<?= $value['testno'] ?>' data-code='<?= 
          $value['testno'] ?>'><?= $value['test'] ?></option>


                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and here is the MasterPage function I'm using to load the view , tell me if I need to add anything else

```
    public function MasterPage($view='',$table='',$da='',$spg='',$szpg='')

{
    if (!empty($table)) {
        $data['result']=$this->Khmodel->get($table,$da,$spg,$szpg,"id 
             desc");
        $data['pages']=$this->Khmodel->pagesno($table,$szpg);
    }
    $data['sview']=$view;
    $data['index']=($view == 'home') ? '' : 'iner_page';


    $getlang =$this->uri->segment(1);//$this->input->cookie('shlang', TRUE);

    if($getlang=='en'){



        $this->lang->load('en', 'en');
        $data['lang']='en';
        $data['nav_align']='right';
        $data['xnav_align']='left';


    }
    else{




        $this->lang->load('ar', 'ar');
        $data['lang']='ar';
        $data['nav_align']='left';
        $data['xnav_align']='right';


    }

    //$this->load->view('main/close');
    $this->load->view('main/header',$data);
    if($view!='home'){
        $this->load->view('main/top_header',$data);

    }
    $this->load->view('main/'.$view);

    $this->load->view('main/footer',$data);

}
```

Comment: what error do you get, could you post the error?

Comment: you have to get the result as `$result->result()` as an object or `$result->result_array()` as an array. then process this object or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this what's worked with me like a charm !

I have used @Sherif Salah  First Part of code INSIDE THE VIEW WITHOUT CONTROLLER OR MODEL 
and It worked actually !!

Thanks for your Help

```
                                $table_one = 'test_name_price';
                                $table_two = 'main_tests';
                                $this->db->select("$table_one.*,$table_two.*");
                                $this->db->join($table_two, "$table_two.id = 
                                     $table_one.test_id", 'left');
                                $this->db->from($table_one);
                                $this->db->where("$table_one.list_id = 
                                         1");
                                $query = $this->db->get();
                                $result_object = $query->result();



                                if (count($result_object) > 0) {

                            foreach ($result_object as $itemsl) {

              echo "<option value='$itemsl->tsprice' data-code='$itemsl- 
                          >testno'>$itemsl->test</option>";

                                    }
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to join tables in codeigniter, but make sure that there are now similar field names or you have to select it individually and rename the field by hand.

```
$table_one = 'table_one_name';
$table_two = 'table_two_name';
$this->db->select("
    $table_one.*,
    $table_two.*
    ");
$this->db->join($table_two, "$table_two.id = $table_one.table_two_id", 'left');
$this->db->from($table_one);
$query = $this->db->get();

$result_object = $query->result();
$result_array = $query->result_array();
```

Note: if your code above is correct, you have to get the result as `$result->result()` as an object or `$result->result_array()` as an array.

---

**Edit:** Here is a quick example about how to use this array in your view, the above code will return array of arrays and you can process this array as:

```
<?php foreach ($result_array as $key => value) : ?>

    <option value='<?= $value['name'] ?>' data-code='<?= $value['code'] ?>'><?= $value['id'] ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note: please keep your logic in your controller, just pass the result to the view.

---

**Edit:** Lets keep it simple for now, supposingly your query worked fine and you can check for this by `var_dump($result)` so now you need to pass this data to the view however you wanna do it but supposingly AGAIN you got you `result` in the controller and all works fine, now you just have to pass it to the view like this:

```
$data = array("result" => $result);
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

and in your view just loop through this array using the variable `result` or whatever you named it and that's it.

**IMHO**.. you should work through codeigniter's documentation and follow any step by step tutorial in codeigniter cause your problem is not that you don't know how to join two table, its about how to use the framework itself.

Comment: Alright I've done the above code in a function in the main controller then now I have tied to pass it to view exactly like you have ofcourse with editing the values but I'm getting this message 

Message: Undefined variable: result_array

Comment: I'm sure you didn't pass it like this `$this->load->view('your_view', array('result_array' => $result_array));`

Comment: You have to pass your data to the view as an array of values.

Comment: Well I didn't really add it but after adding it there is an error under this $result_array saying it's an undefined variable .. keep in mind that the function and the index(){$this->load->view('your_view', array('result_array' => $result_array)); } are in the same controller , thanks for caring!

Comment: Edit your Question and add your modifications in model, controller, view.

Comment: Alright , I haven't added my model because I have not done anything there related to your help

Comment: Well I have added the whole code in my controller in the same addPatient function so the variables are defined and it worked and as using var_dump()  but I still can't figure out why It doesn't wanna load in the page I've already turned it into array , it is only  saying  : Array to string conversion even tho I have used both variables ,

Comment: Anyways Thanks for your Help !